# Would there be any downsides to using CSS without cascading (having each selector fully contain its styles)?

Tags: css

As styling of a website/application gets more complex, and style sheets get bigger, I find that at some point inheritance starts adding to complexity.

You keep scrolling up and down through a long document to restyle a single element. You also need to keep in mind the consequences of any edits to all other tags/selectors that will inherit from it. Things break.

What if instead of that...

- Each element's styles were fully contained within its ID/Class
- Repetitive/common styles were applied using mixins and variables
  (with Sass for example)

That way (my assumption):

1. Elements would be easier and more intuitive to style. Everything that makes an element look certain way is contained in one place. Elements could be customized as much as possible without breaking anything else - nothing inherits from anything else.
2. Global styling would still be possible, and easier too. You define global variables and mixins and use them as you see fit. That way, any element can "inherit" exactly what it needs, and nothing else.
3. Arguably, the resulting CSS would be bigger, but minification and ever increasing internet speed aside - this could make resulting CSS leaner too. Since each element is completely separate from all others (no cascade), you can easily just remove it. While with inheritance we're not always sure if removing something will break something else, so we keep piling up stuff.

Am I overlooking something here? Is there any downside to doing it like this?

Comment: That would be a lot of code for every single element. ;)

Comment: Even [Atomic CSS](https://www.sitepoint.com/atomic-css/) uses the cascade wisely (by "even", I mean it may not be obvious at first glance when you see a bunch of "shortcut classes"). Reminder: font-family, font-size, line-height, etc are inherited from parent element and that'd be a LOT of extra code on every single element of every page/component/template. Do not want. 1/2

Comment: 1/ "through a long document": partials and an automated task to concatenate them in a single CSS file (or 2 or 3 in rare cases). 1 component = 1 file. Every single component in a styleguide (and a second file where there are additional cases I don't want to see daily like "with a long text, with a short one, etc"). 2/ "Global styling": don't. We use Normalize.css and use a (mini-)framework we created ([Knacss](https://github.com/alsacreations/KNACSS)) with minimal global styling. Only components (in the Brad Frost "Atomic Design" way or ITCSS or BEM methodology, YMMV) can style themselves

Comment: What inheritance rules vary between browsers? Who is "scrolling up and down through a long document" and why?

Comment: You can't use CSS without the cascade. The cascade is an integral component in applying styles. Even in the absence of inherited properties, cascading still occurs on a per-element basis (in fact, cascading *never* happens across elements - that's not what cascading means).

Comment: Also, maintainability. If your website has a particular colour and you want to change it, chances are that with this approach you will have to change the `color` in many, many different places.

Comment: @torazaburo deleted that part to avoid confusion. I said it "may" vary, but as I'm learning from comments right now, it could be misunderstanding of terminology on my part.

Comment: @MrLister: Doesn't using variables solve the issue? I define colors on just one place.

Comment: @BoltClock thanks a lot for clarification. Just read some more about it and now understand the difference. Edited my question but it still stands, why wouldn't we "ditch" inheritance then? Having everything that defines a particular element's look in a single place. And shared/reused properties, like brand colors, or border radius can be defined globally and applied as variables/mixins.

Comment: @FelipeAls thanks for your response. May I ask, why "don't" to global styling? Oversimplified example: If some design for example has 3 main colors, why not define them as variables, and then we can restyle the whole design by just editing them. It's following DRY methodology. What would be a better solution and why?

Comment: Global styling (of an element) is adding some border to all h2's and then you have to override it on half of them. Or underlining all links and then having to override it on Tabs, accordions, navigation, etc. From experience, I've been annoyed countless times and will avoid "polluting the global (name)space" to speak in programming language terms (styling elements too much). Classes and components FTW.

Comment: Using variables in a preprocessor: yes (or Custom Properties aka CSS variables when I won't have to support IE11 and any Edge version that doesn't support them). 3/ "restyle a single element": you shouldn't have to. Either you restyle a component (it's restyled everywhere it's used) or you create a variation of it (`*`) (BEM notation with its `--`  and `__`  is a robust convention. My team can do without but if we kept having notation/convention problems, we'd use it) (`*`) and tell the design team/PO/shareholders to calm down on the number of variations ;)

Comment: @FelipeAls seems to me that we actually agree. This is EXACTLY the kind of annoyance I was hoping to avoid by this approach. I guess I used word "global" in a different sense, as in - defining a variable on top of document, to use in any component as needed (so the programming analogy would be $color is a global var, and all components would be "functions" with their own "scope", but also access to this global var)

Comment: I was referring to global as in global styles and saw 1H ago that this question was tagged 'css' but didn't see that you were also referring to Sass in text (it's pretty clear though): so yes global variables are a best practice for having common styles like colors, grid and gutter, margin and padding, etc [Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_variables.scss) goes at length when it comes to variables ^^ (it's a huge framework so it is kind of expected if it's so lengthy)

Comment: @BoltClock Oops yes inheritance isn't cascading and this topic is about inheritance of styles while cascading is more about declarations overriding others for the same element because of multiple stylesheets, rules, specificity, at-media, etc :)

Comment: @FelipeAls: Of course, the cascaded value itself may be inherit, in which case, inheritance becomes completely part of the cascade by way of invocation.

Answer (score -1):

Well Felipe is right that you will want to have your font applied to your html body, and do something similar for any other completely global styles. Otherwise your approach makes complete sense and greatly simplifies your design, which is one of anyones main goals.